# Realm linkingObjects array vs. Results

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a `Book` class and a `ReadingSession` class, with relationships declared like so:

```
public class Book: Object {
    // (…)
    var readingSessions: [ReadingSession] {
        return linkingObjects(ReadingSession.self, forProperty: "book")
    }
}

public class ReadingSession: Object {
    // (…)
    dynamic var book: Book?
}
```

Now I wanted to use Realm’s `Results`’ methods like `filter()` and `sum()` on that `readingSessions` property, but I can't, because it's a regular array.

So I added another computed property to my `Book` class:

```
var sessions: Results<ReadingSession> {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    return realm.objects(ReadingSession).filter("book == %@", self)
}
```

Now when I need to use those methods I go for the `sessions` porperty, and when I don't I use the `readingSessions` array.

So my question is: why is the first way, using the `linkingObjects()` method, recommended in Realm’s documentation? Is there a reason why I shouldn't completely replace that property with my latest one, using Realm’s `Results`? In my experience, working with Realm’s `Results` is usually a lot faster, besides the extra methods, and even if I need a regular array I can just convert the `Results` then. Is there any disadvantage to doing that?

Thanks in advance,

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, there is no better way than what you're currently doing. Using `linkingObjects` would be likely faster as the relationship can be navigated internally bidirectionally and the query doesn't need to be evaluated for the full dataset, so it also depends on the size of that. We plan to change that behavior as seen in [issue #1508](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1508).

Comment: Ah, good to know. I'll keep the `liinkingObjects` then. Thank you!